# Next js link doesn't load the page

Tags: next.js

In my next js project I have the following:

```
      <h4 className="caption-title">
        <Link href="/products">
        <a>{key}</a>
        </Link>
      </h4>
```

The link appears on my page and I click on it but it doesn't go to the page products.
in `pages` directory I have `products.js`

When clicked the url displayed is: `http://localhost:3000/products` but it does NOT go to the page.
If I manually hit this: `http://localhost:3000/products` then it works.
Am I missing something I should be adding?

Comment: I am hitting the same issue, I've got Link all over my app, but only in one case does it not seem to work and I can't figure out why